# how does scikit-learn vectorizer handle punctuation

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn

I understand that:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
```

has tools to deal with punctuation, namely:

```
token_pattern = (?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b
```

but how does it actually work? Can anybody provide a SIMPLE example, e.g. with `grep` or `sed` that makes use of that regular expression? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [**docs;**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

> Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator).

**Explanation of the given regex**

> **`(?u)`** - represent unicode. This will make `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and `\S` perform matching with Unicode semantics.
>
> **`\b`** - Represents word boundary and it assert position of String at boundaries.
>
> **`\w`** - Matches a single word character i.e. **[0-9a-zA-Z_]**.
>
> **`\w+`** - Matches one or more characters within the word boundaries. Notice in the documentation it is clearly mentioned **select tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters.** This is the reason why the regex doesn't contain `\w+` but it contains `\w\w+`.

Since; the given regex contains only alphanumeric characters along with `_`; it discards all the **single letter tokens(such as I, 1, 2, etc.)** as well as any punctuation symbol present.

You can find the implementation of the given regex using `grep` command [**here.**](https://repl.it/repls/SoulfulOnerlookedSystemadministrator)

[**This**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474709/how-to-grep-for-unicode-in-a-bash-script) link might help for implementing `(?u)` in `grep`.